# Not able to view Planet Lab geotiff file

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geotiff-tiff, google-earth, planet

Downloaded geotiff L13-0123E-0323N.tif from #planet lab and tried to open using ArcGIS, Windows Picture viewer, and Google Earth.

However, I don't see the image clearly. 120MB file must be having lot of data and details in it.

---

https://support.planet.com/hc/en-us/articles/211451028--What-can-you-see-

I am referring to this link. Is it possible for me to see a crop from as close as possible to assess its health?

Comment: It would be helpful to provide a link to the data and a screenshot of the problem you are encountering.

Comment: Thanks for your response. You may try downloading an image from this link and try to open using any of the tools mentioned. Which tool do you suggest ?https://api.planet.com/v0/mosaics/landsat8_toa_rgb_mosaic/quads/L13-0302E-0393N/full

Comment: What are you expecting to see clearly? A Landsat 8 image will have a spatial resolution of roughly 30 m, meaning one pixel covers 30 m by 30 m.

Comment: https://support.planet.com/hc/en-us/articles/211451028--What-can-you-see-    I am referring to this link. Is it possible for me to see a crop from as close as possible to assess its health?

Comment: As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about the site and its protocols.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question that should be used to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

The article about what you can see is for Scenes from the Planet satellites, which collect data at 3-5m resolution.

However, the mosaic tile you downloaded was built from a Landsat satellite, so you will only have 30m resolution, as @Kersten pointed out.

You should be able to see crops with Landsat data but remember that Mosaics only contain RGB bands so you'd be better off downloading the Landsat scene for the region you are interested in.

Disclaimer: I work for Planet Labs.